# jQuery & bootstrap input validation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

What it looks like:
[image: input is wrong]
What it should be:
[image: how it shoud be]

For some reason every time I type something in the input box, it adds another error glyph. Can someone help me?

HTML code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="num">
            <input type="text" required pattern="[a-z]{1}[0-9]{7}" name="studo_number" id="studo_number" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Student/docent nummer" tabindex="4" title="Het student/docent nummer moet beginnen met een kleine letter gevolgd door 7 cijfers." maxlength="8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#studo_number").keyup(function () {
        var VAL = this.value;

        var studo = new RegExp('[a-z]{1}[0-9]{7}');

        if (studo.test(VAL)) {
                if ($('#num').hasClass('has-error')){
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            }
            $('#num').addClass('has-success');
            $(this).addClass('has-success');
            $(this).after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
        else{
            $('#num').addClass('has-error');
            $(this).addClass('has-error');
            $(this).after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Every time you `keyup` you add new element (using `$(this).after('<span...`).

Comment: How do I ensure it only adds it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is whenever you `keyup`, a new element is created with the method `.after()`.

Some things like this will resolved your problem, we check before execute something we haven't done it yet before :

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#studo_number").keyup(function () {
        var VAL = this.value;

        var studo = new RegExp('[a-z]{1}[0-9]{7}');

        //Check if input is good and we not already pass in this part
        if (studo.test(VAL) && !$('#num').hasClass('has-success')) {
            //Remove if exist the span glyphicon-remove and the class has-error
            if ($('#num').hasClass('has-error')){
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-remove').remove();
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            }
            $('#num').addClass('has-success');
            $(this).addClass('has-success');
            $(this).after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        } else if (!studo.test(VAL) && !$('#num').hasClass('has-error')) {
            //Remove if exist the span glyphicon-ok and the class has-success
            if ($('#num').hasClass('has-success')){
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-ok').remove();
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-success');
            }
            $('#num').addClass('has-error');
            $(this).addClass('has-error');
            $(this).after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
    });
});
```